# Add multiple Item on quotes with VF Page by a Button

Tags: visualforce, quote, quotelineitem

Hello I am embarking on an important project.
I wish to know if it is possible, since a quotation, to add several article by clicking on a button?
the goal is the following: to build a quote with all items meeting a criterion (Construction range for example).
I was thinking of calling a VF page from a button that would add all lines of items from my Construction line.
this is possible and how to build it.

From a quote I wish to have a button. The purpose of this button is to automatically create quotitem linked to my quote, according to an article selection (by SOQL query !). My quote will include several quoteitem automatically generated by the button. –

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you mean "Construction line" as "Constructor", then the answers below are in that direction. If not, and that you are referring that to be a criteria, then can you edit your post to add more details as what does that signify and when do you want to create the line items?

Comment: Hello sorry if my translation is bad.
Here is my request: 
From a quote I wish to have a button. The purpose of this button is to automatically create quotitem linked to my quote, according to an article selection (by SOQL query !). 
My quote will include several quoteitem automatically generated by the button.

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of calling a VF page from a button that would add all
>   lines of items from my Construction line

Because of salesforce limitation, you cannot do insert/update/delete aka DML inside the constructor of VF controller.

SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AjPRIA0

There is a workaround.
apex:page has action method. Yo can use that to do dml.